# How to get the first unique item of a deep-nested object in an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects that looks like this:

```
const arr  = [
{id: 123, message: { user_id: 4, text: 'fish'}}
{id: 456, message: { user_id: 4, text: 'cow'}}
{id: 789, message: { user_id: 5, text: 'chicken'}}
{id: 010, message: { user_id: 5, text: 'turkey'}}
]
```

I want to return the first item in the array where the message.user_id is unique. I'm expecting a result like this:

```
newArr  = [
{id: 123, message: { user_id: 4, text: 'fish'}}
{id: 789, message: { user_id: 5, text: 'chicken'}}
]
```

I can't seem to find any solution for this. I'm dealing with dynamic data so I can't exactly hardcode the user_id and the array I'm working with contains a lot of elements so I'm trying as much as possible to avoid looping through.

Please what's the best way for me to achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried?  What happened when you tried it?

Comment: I was trying to use filter and reduce functions but I was either getting an empty array or an array of duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a dictionary/object.
2. Iterate through the array and check if
   the id is a key in it

   2.1 If yes, skip

   2.2 If not:

   - Add the row to the output
   - Add the user_id to the dictionary.

```js
const arr  = [
{id: 123, message: { user_id: 4, text: 'fish'}},
{id: 456, message: { user_id: 4, text: 'cow'}},
{id: 789, message: { user_id: 5, text: 'chicken'}},
{id: 010, message: { user_id: 5, text: 'turkey'}}
]

const userIDs = {}

const output = arr.reduce((acc, item) => {
  const user_id = item.message.user_id
  if (userIDs[user_id]) return acc

  acc.push(item)
  userIDs[user_id] = true;
  return acc
},[])

console.log(output)
```

Comment: This is pretty straightforward and it's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much, I wouldn't have guessed this at all.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another similar solution but with a bit modified syntax, I hope this will be helpful:

```js
const arr  = [
{id: 123, message: { user_id: 4, text: 'fish'}},
{id: 456, message: { user_id: 4, text: 'cow'}},
{id: 789, message: { user_id: 5, text: 'chicken'}},
{id: 010, message: { user_id: 5, text: 'turkey'}}
];
const uniqueResult = (Object.values(arr.reduce(function(acc, item) {
  if (!acc[item.message.user_id]) {
    acc[item.message.user_id] = item;
  }
  return acc;
}, {})));
console.log(uniqueResult);
```